# How split string at semi-colon that appears before a colon

Tags: java, regex

How can I split this string `power:110V;220V;Color:Pink;White;Type:1;2;Condition:New;Used;`
into these 4 strings

```
power:110V;220V;
Color:Pink;White;
Type:1;2;
Condition:New;Used;
```

Comment: Will each line always have exactly one label and two values?

Comment: Exactly one lable but It  can have more than 2 values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split your input according to the below regex.

```
string.split("(?<=;)(?=\\w+:)");
```

The above regex would match all the boundaries which exists next to a semicolon and the  boundary must be followed by one or more word characters and a colon.

**OR**

```
string.split("(?<=;)(?=[^;:]*:)");
```

**Example:**

```
String s = "power:110V;220V;Color:Pink;White;Type:1;2;Condition:New;Used;";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=;)(?=\\w+:)");
for(String i: parts)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```